# Как реализовать scrollbar на JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

http://jsfiddle.net/7hd4s0rv/

Допишите, плиз, никак не получается доделать этот скролл бар.  Буквально, самый простой, чтоб скролл в зависимости от высоты контента изменял свою высоту.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот тут ( http://manos.malihu.gr/repository/custom-scrollbar/demo/examples/complete_examples.html ) есть то, что вам нужно, с огромным количеством настроек, "колбеков" и оттестированными багами со всеми браузерами, включая IE8 и мобильные.